# embedding scriping language code within XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, embedded-resource

How to embed a Lua script or IronPython/IronRuby script within the XAML definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://www.thinkbottomup.com.au/site/blog/Embedding_DLR_Scripts_in_XAML_Part_1 for a really good tutorial on doing this. The only shortcoming in his example is the way he defined the routed event handler only allows you to define a single event to be handled but it was easy to modify it to define a collection of events instead. IMHO this is a great way to move UI behavior into the view but I'll probably be slammed by the purists for saying it.